# R Distance from Point to Line: Negative if within shape

Tags: shapefile, r, distance, sf, st

I'm working with Brazilian deforestation data - specifically two sf objects:

- A point shapefile on environmental fines (centroid of land plots that have been fined for deforestation).
- A polygon of (unioned) municipalities.

My aim is to calculate the nearest distance from each point to the municipal boundary line. I can do this using `st_distance`, however I would like the distance to be negative for points that are within the municipality polygon (as in picture below). Could anyone please advise?

```
deforest <- st_read("Environmental_Fines.shp")
munic <- st_read("Municipalities_Union.shp")
```

[image: Municipalities]

Answer (score 1):

Outine solution:

1. Cast the polygons to lines using `st_cast` and compute distances of pounts to lines (otherwise you get zero for the distance of points inside polygons).
2. Use `st_intersects` on the points/polygons to test if point is inside polygon, and negate the distance for those that are.

Comment: Thanks very much! I've just added a column to my Deforestation df with st_intersects, with value 0/1 - however it's been added in list format (integer(0) or 1).  Do you know how this can be converted to an object within the df instead?

Comment: `st_intersects` returns a list because a point could be in several polys. If you are sure this isn't the case (maybe you only have one poly) then you can compute a "is it in a poly?" with `lengths(st_intersection(....)) > 0` - note use of `lengths` (not `length`) which returns zero for `integer(0)` when there's no intersection. Use that to make a vector to put in your data frame.